# Google Sheets>New Entries pop up at the top

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

On the attendance tracker below incidents are affiliated with a point value system. Each entry is entered on the left (itemized with details) and consolidated on the right (past the black line). On the right-hand side, the 'Action Taken' column(Column U) is populated based on the number in the 'Total Points' column (Column T).

I would like the 'Status' column (Column V) to revert back to 'Not Started', and reflect a different color when the number changes (increases/decreases) in the 'Total Points' column.  I would like the new entries to also pop up at the top. Let me know, please!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bfs41hC6qxLadwuVv1qc4HV1hDoiw9bGi9UsiSzeG_0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there are two different topics in your issue. The first one is to modify the V column after every edit on the T column. The second one is to add new entries at the top of the table. With the following functions, you will be able to accomplish both.

The first function will change the color and value of the V column after every edit on the T column. It will use an [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) of a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) to run. I choose [azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_(color)) as an example colour, but you can change it.

The second function will insert a new blank row at the top of your table, and will populate it later with different values. I wrote example values to exemplify the code, but you can fill it with your chosen values.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    'Attendance Tracker');
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 20) {
    var status = e.range.offset(0, 2);
    status.setBackgroundRGB(0, 127, 255);
    status.setValue('Not Started');
  }
}

function newEntry() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(
    'Attendance Tracker');
  sheet.insertRowBefore(3);
  sheet.getRange(3, 1, 1, 23).setValues(["Value A", "Value B", 
  "Value C" … "Value W"]);
}
```

Please, remember to update the values row separating each value with commas (notice how I used «…» to make the example shorter). Do not hesitate to ask for any additional clarification or for further help.

Comment: Good afternoon Jacques, Good afternoon Jacques, hope you're having a pleasant Monday, the code provided is running on the first sheet ("Form Responses 3"), I would like it to run on the tab labeled, "Attendance Tracker". I would like the latest entry (which populates in Column A) to show up on R2, and have column V ('Status') to be reverted to "Not Started".